# GitHub GraphQL API - Branch Protection Rule - How do I get "Require a pull request before merging"?

Tags: github-api

I'd like to get the value set for the *Require a pull request before merging* via the GraphQL API. I'm not finding or am missing the information for the docs on the [BranchProtectionRule](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#branchprotectionrule). I'd imagine this should be obvious but isn't for me at the moment.

[image]

And for the purposes of helping out anyone else on a related path, here's my code for getting the branch protection rules using PowerShell and GitHub GraphQL API:

```
$JsonContent = & "gh" api graphql -H 'X-Github-Next-Global-ID: 1' -F owner="$repoowner" -F name="$reponame" -f query='
    query($name: String!, $owner: String!) {
        repository(owner: $owner, name: $name) {
            branchProtectionRules(first: 100) {
                nodes {
                    matchingRefs(first: 100) {
                    nodes {
                        name
                    }
                }
                pattern
                allowsDeletions
                allowsForcePushes
                dismissesStaleReviews
                isAdminEnforced
                pushAllowances(first: 100) {
                    nodes {
                      actor {
                        ... on App {
                          id
                          name
                          slug
                        }
                        ... on Team {
                          id
                          name
                          slug
                        }
                        ... on User {
                          id
                          name
                          login
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                requiresApprovingReviews
                requiredApprovingReviewCount
                requiresCodeOwnerReviews
                requiresCommitSignatures
                requiresConversationResolution
                requiresLinearHistory
                requiresStatusChecks
                requiredStatusCheckContexts
                requiresStrictStatusChecks
                restrictsPushes
                restrictsReviewDismissals
                }
            }
        }
    }
'
```

Comment: I've also been unable to find this... I've posted a question on the GitHub discussion board to see if anyone there knows. I'll update this if I find out anything useful! https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/57406

Comment: consider me helped :) thank you for sharing the retrieval of branch protections.  

I kept coming across ways that queried branches first then off of the branches i could inspect the protections.  This gives me the branch protections and nothing else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* I've found the answer; confusingly, the **Require a pull request before merging setting** seems to correspond with the `requiresApprovingReviews` value *in conjunction* with the `requiredApprovingReviewCount` value—despite the setting in the GitHub UI not mentioning reviews at all.

To try and figure this out, I selected *all* available properties in my GraphQL query for a single repository, then toggled the setting on and off to see what was different.

```
query MyQuery {
  repository(name: "MY_REPO_NAME", owner: "MY_ORGANISATION") {
    branchProtectionRules(first: 10) {
      edges {
        node {
          allowsDeletions
          allowsForcePushes
          blocksCreations
          dismissesStaleReviews
          isAdminEnforced
          lockAllowsFetchAndMerge
          lockBranch
          pattern
          requireLastPushApproval
          requiredApprovingReviewCount
          requiredDeploymentEnvironments
          requiresApprovingReviews
          requiresCodeOwnerReviews
          requiresCommitSignatures
          requiresConversationResolution
          requiresDeployments
          requiresLinearHistory
          requiresStatusChecks
          requiresStrictStatusChecks
          restrictsPushes
          restrictsReviewDismissals
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So the results of that were that with the setting unchecked:

[image: "Require a pull request before merging" not checked]

We get:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "branchProtectionRules": {
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "allowsDeletions": false,
              "allowsForcePushes": false,
              "blocksCreations": false,
              "dismissesStaleReviews": false,
              "isAdminEnforced": false,
              "lockAllowsFetchAndMerge": false,
              "lockBranch": false,
              "pattern": "master",
              "requireLastPushApproval": false,
              "requiredApprovingReviewCount": null,
              "requiredDeploymentEnvironments": [],
              "requiresApprovingReviews": false,
              "requiresCodeOwnerReviews": false,
              "requiresCommitSignatures": false,
              "requiresConversationResolution": false,
              "requiresDeployments": false,
              "requiresLinearHistory": false,
              "requiresStatusChecks": false,
              "requiresStrictStatusChecks": true,
              "restrictsPushes": false,
              "restrictsReviewDismissals": false
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And with the setting checked:

[image: "Require a pull request before merging" checked]

We get:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "branchProtectionRules": {
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "allowsDeletions": false,
              "allowsForcePushes": false,
              "blocksCreations": false,
              "dismissesStaleReviews": false,
              "isAdminEnforced": false,
              "lockAllowsFetchAndMerge": false,
              "lockBranch": false,
              "pattern": "master",
              "requireLastPushApproval": false,
              "requiredApprovingReviewCount": 0,
              "requiredDeploymentEnvironments": [],
              "requiresApprovingReviews": true,
              "requiresCodeOwnerReviews": false,
              "requiresCommitSignatures": false,
              "requiresConversationResolution": false,
              "requiresDeployments": false,
              "requiresLinearHistory": false,
              "requiresStatusChecks": false,
              "requiresStrictStatusChecks": true,
              "restrictsPushes": false,
              "restrictsReviewDismissals": false
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So the difference is:

[image: Before/after diff showing that requiresApprovingReviews and requiredApprovingReviewCount are true/0 after checking the setting]

So it seems you can say that if `requiresApprovingReviews` is `true` then the **Require a pull request before merging** setting is enabled for that repository. The `requiredApprovingReviewCount` will be `0` if no PR approvals are required to merge.